# Solution to Poisson's equation for linear function

Tags: markov-chains, ergodic-theory, poissons-equation

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is an ergodic Markov chain with state space $\mathcal{X}$, transition operator $P$, and stationary distribution $\pi$. Let $A:\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix valued function defined on $\mathcal{X}$. For any $x \in \mathcal{X}$, the Poisson's equation for $A$ is given by

$$\hat{A}(x) - P \hat{A}(x) = A(x) - \pi(A)$$

where $\hat{A}: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is the solution to Poisson's equation, $P\hat{A}(x) = \int_{y \in \mathcal{X}} \hat{A}(y) P(dy \mid x)$, and $\pi(A) = \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} A(x) \pi(dx)$ is the expected value of $A$ under the stationary distribution $\pi$. I understand that in general it is very difficult, or impossible, to obtain a closed form expression for the solution to the Poisson's equation. However, in this case, given that we are only dealing with linear functions, is there a closed form expression for $\hat{A}$?

Comment: Is this really called Poisson's equation? To my knowledge (and the description of the tag [poissons-equation]), its a PDE $-\Delta u = f$

Comment: Yes, this is the Poisson's equation from probability theory. I believe it is somehow related to the PDE version you mentioned, though I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Sorry, can I also ask what hat denotes in $\hat A$? (and if you expect ergodicity to play a role, maybe consider tagging [ergodic-theory]?)

Comment: $\hat{A}$ is the solution to Poisson's equation. I've edited the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: The analogy to Poisson's equation is that $I-P$ is the "positive definite generator" (i.e. the negative of the actual generator) of the stochastic process. $-\Delta$ plays the same role for $\sqrt{2}$ times standard Brownian motion. Still there is no reason to expect a closed form solution at anywhere near this level of generality.

Comment: @Ian are there conditions on $P$ and $\pi$ under which we can expect a closed form solution?

Comment: It would really be all on P, because it basically comes down to inverting $I-P$. That can only rarely be done in closed form though (e.g. you could probably do it for a simple random walk).

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.